# missing icuuc72.dll breaks miktex latex

Tags: xetex, unicode

I just upgraded to the latest version of Miktex and I am getting a message when I am trying to compile with xelatex that "the code execution cannot proceed because icuuc72.dll was not found".

After some check I realised that the icuuc72.dll is part of the International Components of Unicode (ICU), which recently released version 72.
I also found out that the "iccuc.dll" (and a few other relevant) comes with "miktex-bin-icu-x64". However, when I downloaded the latest lzma from a random repository, I found version "icuuc60.dll".

I need to know whether this is something other users are also experience? And whether there is a way to resolve this. E.g can I downgrade or select another version of the miktex-xetex?

Comment: This seems like a problem that should be posted at the MikTeX issue tracker, https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks for the suggestion. I posted it. I got the reply that it was resolved. I will keep this until tomorrow, so that if someone runs into the same problem knows what happened, and then I will delete the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been resolved as of 26th of November.
See [issue number 1232 in miktek](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1232#issuecomment-1327435188) .

Now the "miktex-bin-icu-x64" package contains icuuc72.dll